# Computercraft error attempt to call nil on a turtle.inspectDown() return value

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I have an error on line 42

```lua
if parseBlock(bl1.name) then
```

parseBlock is a function I made to do some checks to see if that block is an ore (I have many different ores from different mods that I have in there)
I narrowed it down to this line

```lua
local success1,bl1 = turtle.inspectDown()
```

success1 is true
bl1 is nil

Wondering why inspectDown() returned nil? There is a block below the turtle as well.
The block is: undergroundbiomes:igneous_stone

I went into the lua program to do the same lines of code, yet it does it properly  printing the name of the block below it.

Comment: `parseBlock` is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently cannot confirm this in the computercraft API, but if I remember correctly it does follow the Lua convention of returning either a value or nil+message on error. What this means is:

When an error happens, the function will return `nil` and an error description as a string. When *no* error happens though, the function will just return its result. The difference here is that the result will be the **first** return value of the function.

Normally this can be handled like this:

```lua
local result, err = some_function()
if result then
   do_something_with(result)
else
   print("Error! " .. err)
end
```

However, while that is likely the reason for `success1` being nil, it doesn't explain the error message you are getting. Lua is telling you that you are trying to call `nil`, and there is only one function call in the code you provided: `parseBlock`.

As Egor Skriptunoff pointed out, `parseBlock` is most likely `nil`, which causes the error when you attempt to call it. You can confirm this by simply adding `print(parseBlock)` above the line where you call it and if it says `nil`, then you've found the cause of the problem.

Otherwise, you'd have to add a bit more information:

- The exact error message you're getting
- a few lines of surrounding code are often useful (3 previous and 3 following as a rule of thumb)
- information on how your code is structured (Are all functions in one file? Are you loading `parseBlock` from somewhere else? etc.)